# Battery Life: 1and half to two hours

Tags: battery-life

Is the battery life of 1 and half - two hours vbad for a new laptop? Is this value very low? I have a HP 4320s Laptop (which comes under the category of Corporate Laptop), i3 Processor, almost nothing in graphics card, 280GB hard disk space, 3GB RAM. The Screen Size is just 13 inch, internet usage is through wi-fi. I do not play any games at all and also do not play any HD Videos - just Surfing Internet and reading documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends a bit on what you are doing with the computer, but generally yes: it is very low. If you are playing games/watching HD material/utilizing Flash to a large part of that time, it might be reasonable. If the computer is idling, then no, it is not reasonable.

Try to just have your computer idling (check the CPU charts during, so you don't have a rogue process eating 100% CPU constantly) after a full charge and see how long it lasts. If it lasts at least 4 hours, the manufacturer may very well say that they have done nothing wrong in their marketing, sadly.

Comment: When Idle, the batty life is around 2hrs, games do not run in my laptop at all, I do not play HD movies. The batty life is around 1 and half hr. when just surfing the net or reading a pdf document. I have tried reinstalling windows, but it didn't work.

Comment: Contact the seller with this information. Depending on country and laws, it might be a very different scenario, though.

Comment: What are your power setting set to? Is the battery a genuine HP branded original/replacement?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, considering that the advertised [battery life](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/ca/en/sm/WF06a/321957-321957-64295-3955552-3955552-4145545.html) for that model ranges from `4 - 10` hours.